# Change of textbox value based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my working code. When checkbox is checked textbox value get changed but the only problem is that value of textbox not getting to it default value after uncheck.So my question is how to get defaut value of textbox after uncheck?

```
<div class="invoice">
     <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
     <span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" id="total" value="$90"/>


$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
});

if (total == 0) {
    $('#total').val('');
}
else {
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
}
});
```

Comment: it's not clear, what is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $defaultValue=$('#total').val();
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.inv-total').text().substring(1));
});

if (total == 0) {
    $('#total').val($defaultValue);
}
else {
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
}
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoice">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
<span class="inv-total">$100</span>
</div>

<input type="text" id="total" value="$90"/>
```